# Where do I find prebuilt binutils and compilers for obsolete operating systems?

Tags: solaris, gcc

I just obtained a Sun SPARCstation 20 and installed SunOS 4.1.4 on it. I'd like to build some software on it with something a little more modern than its stock *pre-ANSI* C compiler, and without the huge bootstrapping process involved in building the entire toolchain myself.

Is there a canonical site for either SunOS 4.1 binaries, or for prebuilt GNU toolchains that might include older operating systems like SunOS?

Comment: If you can find it, Sun Workshop versions <= 5 have compilers that will work on SunOS 4. 1. They're not gcc, though.

Comment: Thanks! If nothing else, they may make a better tool chain for bootstrapping GCC than Sun's stock `cc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not so sure that you're going to be able to find binaries for a platform this old. I spent a good 45 minutes looking and came up empty-handed. There used to be `ftp.freesunware.com`, but it seems to have shut down long ago. My suggestion would be to start by getting a working `gcc`. I think you'll have better luck if you can update the machine to SunOS 5.x, firstly.

To compile gcc on SunOS 4.1.4, first we need to start with a GCC version that was known to work on this platform. I find evidence that [2.7.2.3](http://www.netgull.com/gcc/old-releases/gcc-2/) - [2.8.1](http://www.netgull.com/gcc/old-releases/gcc-2/) compiled properly on SunOS 4.1.4.  Maybe you'd even get lucky with [2.95.3](http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-2.95.3/) So, start with downloading GCC from one of the previous links (official GCC mirror). Compile as follows:

```
./configure --build=sparc-sun-sunos4.1.4
make bootstrap-lean
cd objdir && make install
```

You don't necessarily need to install [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) first, but it may help, and if not, you'll want to install it afterwards.

I really think you're going to be forced to compile the toolchain yourself, unless you can find someone with a SunOS 4 machine who has already done this and can give you the binaries. Be prepared--compiling the complete toolchain may take upwards of a week, and you will undoubtedly run into challenges. Get started, and if you get hopelessly stuck, post new questions here with specifics of where you're stuck. I hope this helps, and sorry that I can't find the binaries!

**Edit**

Also, unless you have a reason to keep it on SunOS 4.x, you'll probably have a lot better luck if you can get it updated to SunOS 5.6 (Solaris 2.6). There are [many binaries available for 5.6](http://unixpackages.com/packages/solaris-2-6-sparc), including the toolchain components you need. You may be able to find a copy on eBay, or, torrents are available (I'm not sure about the legality of this, being very outdated software, so, try to find a legal means of purchasing a license).

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it would be reasonably feasible to build a cross-compiler on my Linux box (Ubuntu 15.10 on a fast i7 with tons of RAM and an SSD), and cross-compile the toolchain against the 4.1.4 libraries either copied or NFS-mounted to the Linux box?

Comment: This might, indeed, be a better approach. I had a SparcStation 10 with SunOS 5.6 (early Solaris, technically, and sorry, if I still did, I'd upload the binaries!) and compiling anything was a painfully-slow experience. I'm not very experienced with cross-compiling, but I think this is a worthwhile path. I'd start with getting a simple application to cross-compile and then try doing it with GCC. Like I said in my post, I'd stick to older versions of software that may have actually been tested on these machines, as no one is testing GCC 5 on SunOS :)

Comment: As a starting point, I believe you would have to add `--host=sun-triplet --target=sun-triplet` when compiling the compiler, and then `--host=sun-triplet` when compiling anything else, where `sun-triplet` is the triplet of the Sun OS system.

Comment: Also see my edit about upgrading to a slightly more recent OS :)

Comment: I think you mean [`sunfreeware.com`](http://sunfreeware.com/), not `freesunware.com` - it's still around but for Solaris 2.5 & later, not the older SunOS 4 (aka Solaris 1.x).

Comment: That could be. The post I had found references `freesunware.com`, but that could have been a mistake in the original post. `sunfreeware.com` is still around, but they've moved everything to `unixpackages.com`

Comment: Since I’m specifically setting this up as a retrocomputing system, I’m keeping it at SunOS 4.1.4 for the time being. If I decide to go multiprocessor, then I may update to Solaris 2.6, but that’ll be the highest I take it. Thanks for your help! (Oh, and the triple is `sparc-sun-sunos4.1.4` of course.)